# HTML5 Canvas Elements styling?

Tags: html, css, canvas

I want to style the canvas elements (like filltext etc) which I have drawn on canvas.

For example, I want text to have inside shadow. (i think it is called inset!)

Is there any way to style elements within canvas.. using CSS3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.
Css is applied to dom elements, while the "*elements within canvas*" do not exist in the document object model. They are just simple image data.

But, You can always use the native js function `setShadow` in the canvas context. You can see it [here](http://uupaa-js-spinoff.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/uupaa-excanvas.js/demo/9_1_canvas_shadow_text_direction.html) in action.